# Print something in a tlp file if a field isnt empty

Tags: 7, theming

I need to print some html in a node tpl file if a certain field is not empty. The follwing is giving me a white screen:

```
<?php if (!empty($content['field_hotel_sat_nav'])) {
                        print '<h1>The field is not empty</h1>'
            }
?>
```

Comment: The white screen would surely be caused by the missing semi-colon at the end of the `print` statement...nothing wrong with the call to `empty()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php 
  if ($content['field_hotel_sat_nav'] != '') { 

    //Do something 

  }
?>
```